# Good wii games for co-op play that are easy to learn?

Tags: game, multi-user, gaming, wii

I'm looking for some good wii games for local multiplayer with family and friends.  I personally love games that have high skill and take a while to learn, but not everyone is willing to take the time to get over a high learning curve.

What I need in the type of wii games I'm looking for:

1. Preferably in the cheap range (used).  A lot of wii games are under ten dollars, these are usually not made by Nintendo.  This is only preferable, feel free to mention ones that are more expensive if they are realy good.
2. Relatively easy to learn and accessible, so not a ton of controlls to memorize.  It's great if they have depth as long as you can still have fun and feel like you understand what you are doing without having to have played the game for a long time.  So they need to be pick up and play.
3. Local multiplayer, more players the better, but 2 is fine.
4. Family friendly.  Preferably rated Everone although Everyone 10+ is fine if it's due to fantasy violence.
5. Fun.  (obviously)
6. Already hinted to it, but I prefer if they are games with depth as long as you can pick up and play them without having to spend a ton of time learing them.  It would be cool if you can get better at them over time, but they are accessible at the beginning.I already stated this, but I wanted to make it clear in a point thatI like skill, as long as there isn't a giant learning curve.

I already have both wii sports.  They are both great, I would prefer a little more depth, but all and all pretty good.  my favorite game mode is golf.

I also have super mario strikers charged.  This one is good too and has some great depth, a *little* easier to pick up at first might be good though.

(I have super smash bros brawl too, I love it but the number of buttons keeps some people from playing it.)

Edit:

I have 2 wii remotes with the motion plus addon, and 2 numchucks to go with them.

Comment: Note the Wii is discontinued and as such you may be hard-pressed to find software or accessories for it.  That said, do you have the Wii Motion+ add-on?  [Wii Sports Resort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Sports_Resort) is a decent successor to the basic Wii Sports game.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're interested in upgrading to the Switch, [Snipperclips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipperclips) is a good intro/gateway game.

Comment: Hi @BenThompson , Yes, I have wii motion +, I also have Wii Sports Resort already, (I said i owned both wii sports games, np) they are both pretty good.  Yeah I'm aware that the wii is discontinued, but so far ebay has a good supply of games and hardware.  I edited my question to include my hardware.  Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough.  The only game I got Wii Motion+ for was Skyward Sword which doesn't check any of your boxes.  That said, I did get to play [Excite Truck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excite_Truck) at GDC2009.  I didn't pick it up (no console at the time) but had a blast.  Simple enough to figure out the basic gameplay from the demo.  However, the split-screen multiplayer is competitive and not co-op, hence comment and not answer.

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean co-op like co-operative, I was thinking couch co-op, so I should have said local multiplayer instead, my bad.  I edited it to make it more clear.  I've heard good things about Excitebots which is the sequel to excite truck.  Games like that are probably what I'm looking for in the skill/depth, pretty easy to pick up(it looks like) but enough depth so that you can enjoy getting better.  thnx!

Comment: Also, another suggestion but with Brawl instead of the standard remote-and-nunchuck config, try some of the alternate control schemes like the [sideways remote](https://www.smashbros.com/wii/en_us/howto/basic/basic07.html).  This reduces the inputs from roughly 900 buttons to just a d-pad and four buttons.

Comment: I'm hoping you get some good answers from others.  Regardless, remember that you are always welcome to self-answer with one or more answers at any time with your discoveries.  I might actually consider picking up a used wii if you get good answers or post self-answers!

Answer (score 0):

I think the game "Boom blox" (or "Boom blox 2") suits your wishes well.